# Non-sequential substitution in SymPy

Tags: python, math, substitution, symbolic-math, sympy

I'm trying to use [SymPy][1] to substitute multiple terms in an expression at the same time. I tried the [subs function][2] with a dictionary as parameter, but found out that it substitutes sequentially.

```
In : a.subs({a:b, b:c})
Out: c
```

The problem is the first substitution resulted in a term that can be substituted by the second substitution, but it should not (for my cause).

Any idea on how to perform the substitutions simultaneously, without them interfering with each other?

**Edit:**
This is a real example

```
In [1]: I_x, I_y, I_z = Symbol("I_x"), Symbol("I_y"), Symbol("I_z")

In [2]: S_x, S_y, S_z = Symbol("S_x"), Symbol("S_y"), Symbol("S_z")

In [3]: J_is = Symbol("J_IS")

In [4]: t = Symbol("t")

In [5]: substitutions = (
(2 * I_x * S_z, 2 * I_x * S_z * cos(2 * pi * J_is * t) + I_y * sin(2 * pi * J_is * t)),
(I_x,  I_x * cos(2 * pi * J_is * t) + 2 * I_x * S_z * sin(2 * pi * J_is * t)),
(I_y,  I_y * cos(2 * pi * J_is * t) - 2 * I_x * S_z * sin(2 * pi * J_is * t))
)

In [6]: (2 * I_x * S_z).subs(substitutions)
Out[7]: (I_y*cos(2*pi*J_IS*t) - 2*I_x*S_z*sin(2*pi*J_IS*t))*sin(2*pi*J_IS*t) + 2*S_z*(I_x*cos(2*pi*J_IS*t) + 2*I_x*S_z*sin(2*pi*J_IS*t))*cos(2*pi*J_IS*t)
```

Only the appropriate substitution should happen, in this case only the first one. So the expected output should be the following:

```
In [6]: (2 * I_x * S_z).subs(substitutions)
Out[7]: I_y*sin(2*pi*J_IS*t) + 2*I_x*S_z*cos(2*pi*J_IS*t)
```

Comment: Can you give a real example of your substitutions so I can see what the problem is. The problem you have above can be solved by ~unutbu's answer.

Comment: @PreludeAndFugue I've added a real examples, my old examples were too much simplified and not really useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The current version of sympy provides the keyword simultaneous. The complicated operations in the previous answers are no more necessary:

```
In [1]: (x*sin(y)).subs([(x,y),(y,x)],simultaneous=True)
Out[1]: y⋅sin(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `subs(self,*args)` method is defined (in part) this way:

```
In [11]: x.subs??
...
sequence = args[0]
if isinstance(sequence, dict):
    return self._subs_dict(sequence)
elif isinstance(sequence, (list, tuple)):
    return self._subs_list(sequence)
```

If you pass `subs` a dict, you lose control over the order of the substitutions.
While if you pass `subs` a list or tuple, you can control the order.

This doesn't allow you to do simultaneous substitutions. That would lead to difficulties if the user were to pass stuff like `x.subs([(x,y),(y,x)])`. So I doubt sympy has a method for doing simultaneous substitutions. Instead I believe all substutions are either unordered (if you pass a dict) or, at best, done by a 1-pass ordered substitution (if you pass a list or tuple):

```
In [17]: x.subs([(x,y),(y,z)])
Out[18]: z

In [19]: x.subs([(y,z),(x,y)])
Out[19]: y
```

PS. `_subs_list(self, sequence)` is defined (in part) like this:

```
In [14]: x._subs_list??
...
    for old, new in sequence:
        result = result.subs(old, new)
```

This nails down the order in which the subs are done.

Comment: I've added a second example, the order of the substitutions seems to vary according to some principle I don't understand.

Comment: You could reproduce it using OrderedDict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080450/non-sequential-substitution-in-sympy/3080803#3080803

Answer (score 1):

Example for [@~unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080450/non-sequential-substitution-in-sympy/3080776#3080776):

```
>>> import ordereddict # collections.OrderedDict in Python 2.7+
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x,y,z = symbols('xyz')
>>> x.subs(ordereddict.OrderedDict([(x,y),(y,z)]))
y
>>> x.subs(ordereddict.OrderedDict([(y,z),(x,y)]))
z
```

Comment: Thanks, so it is somewhat unpredictable with normal dicts because they are unsorted. Unfortunately in my case the order does not matter, the substitutions trample over each other regardless of the order.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the edited question.

In your example you can use some temporary variables which will not be over-written be subsequent substitutions. Then, once all of the potentially overlapping substitutions have been made, you can replace the temporary variables with the real ones.

This example works for the question, if your full problem contains more complex substitutions, I think you should still be able to create temporary variables to avoid overlapping substitutions.

```
from sympy import Symbol, sin, cos, pi

I_x, I_y, I_z = Symbol("I_x"), Symbol("I_y"), Symbol("I_z")
S_x, S_y, S_z = Symbol("S_x"), Symbol("S_y"), Symbol("S_z")
J_is = Symbol("J_IS")
t = Symbol("t")
I_x_temp, I_y_temp, I_z_temp = Symbol("I_x_temp"), Symbol("I_y_temp"), Symbol("I_z_temp")

f = 2*I_x*S_z
answer = I_y*sin(2*pi*J_is*t) + 2*I_x*S_z*cos(2*pi*J_is*t)

subs1a = [
    (2*I_x*S_z, 2*I_x_temp*S_z*cos(2*pi*J_is*t) + I_y_temp*sin(2*pi*J_is*t)),
    (I_x,  I_x_temp*cos(2* pi*J_is*t) + 2*I_x_temp*S_z*sin(2*pi*J_is*t)),
    (I_y,  I_y_temp*cos(2*pi*J_is*t) - 2*I_x_temp*S_z* sin(2*pi*J_is*t))
]

subs_temp = [(I_x_temp, I_x), (I_y_temp, I_y), (I_z_temp, I_z)]

print f
f = f.subs(subs1a)
print f
f = f.subs(subs_temp)
print f
print f == answer # True
```

Note, you can also perform two substitutions back to back:

```
f.subs(subs1a).subs(subs_temp) == answer
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keyword `simultaneous` will do non-clashing subs regardless of the input (dict or sequence):

```
>>> x.subs([(x,y),(y,z)],simultaneous=1)
y
>>> x.subs([(y,z),(x,y)],simultaneous=1)
y
```