# Simultaneous replacement of SymPy logic function

Tags: python, sympy

I came across a problem substituting variables in logical formulas in Sympy.
Here's a minimal example -

```
from sympy import *
x, y = symbols('x y')
Nand(x, y).subs({x: Nand(x, y)}, simultaneous=True)
```

This fails both in my local interperter, and in the live shell on [SymPy Docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=subs#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs), with the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/49.400254913747479351/sympy/sympy/core/basic.py", line 889, in subs
    d = Dummy(commutative=new.is_commutative)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/49.400254913747479351/sympy/sympy/core/symbol.py", line 205, in __new__
    cls._sanitize(assumptions, cls)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/49.400254913747479351/sympy/sympy/core/symbol.py", line 65, in _sanitize
    '%scommutativity must be True or False.' % whose)
ValueError: Dummy commutativity must be True or False.
```

Other formulations I've tried, like replacing "Nand"s with "And", don't fail. Setting simultaneous=False also doesn't fail, but will not give the desired result if I want to replace y at the same time (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080450/non-sequential-substitution-in-sympy) for details why).

Is this a bug in SymPy, or am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SymPy. [Class `Not`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/logic/boolalg.py#L603) does not have `is_commutative` property set, and does not inherit it either. As a result, `Nand(x, y)` (which is `Not(And(x, y))` has "None" for "commutative" assumption, and this is not acceptable for Dummy creation method, which attempts to create a dummy symbol with the same assumptions.  This problem does not occur for `And`, because `And` inherits `is_commutative=True` from [`LatticeOp`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/operations.py#L401) class.

The way to fix this in SymPy seems to be to add `is_commutative=True` to class `Not`.

Workarounds on user side include: using `Or(Not(x), Not(y))` instead of `Nand(x, y)`

```
Nand(x, y).subs({x: Or(Not(x), Not(y))}, simultaneous=True)
```

(this returns `~(y & (~x | ~y))`)

and fixing the classes on your own:

```
class Not(Not):
    is_commutative = True

class Nand(Nand):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, *args):
        return Not(And(*args))      

Nand(x, y).subs({x: Nand(x, y)}, simultaneous=True)
```

(returns `~(y & ~(x & y))`.)